# get alphabat instead of word jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I wan't to get string instead of word. how can i do this.

php file code

```
<?php
    $countries = array("Afghanistan", "Albania");
    $response=array("countries"=>$countries);  
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

html file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("button").click(function(
     $.ajax({
     type:'GET',
     url:'./countries.php',
     data:{countries:true},
     cache:false,
     async:false,
     success:function(data){
     var str="";
     for(i=0;i<data.length;i++)
       {$("tbody.new").append("<tr><td>" + data[i] + "</td><td></td>              <tr>");}
```

result is like this a f g a every word is separate line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified the accepted data type in ajax options object. That's why you are getting a json string instead of parced json data. 
Change your code as shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("button").click(function(
     $.ajax({
     type:'GET',
     url:'./countries.php',
     data:{countries:true},
     dataType: 'json',
     cache:false,
     async: true,
     success:function(data){
         var str = "";
         for (i = 0; i < data["countries"].length; i++){
            $("tbody.new").append("<tr><td>" + data["countries"][i] + "</td><td></td><tr>");
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `dataType:'json'` since you aren't setting appropriate content type header on server.

This will tell `$ajax` to parse response to array or object in success callback.

Then you want to access the proper property of the response object which will be `data.countries` which is an array

Also `async:false` is a terrible practice. It should never ever be used and you should be seeing deprecation warnings in browser console